# Volley and handling Flickr errorCodes

Tags: android, android-volley, flickr

I implemented a simple volley custom request following [Android developer guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

```
GsonRequest<FlickrResponsePhotos> gsonObjRequest = new GsonRequest<>(myRequest.getRequestMethodType(), myRequest.getApiUrl(),
                FlickrResponsePhotos.class, null, new Response.Listener<FlickrResponsePhotos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(FlickrResponsePhotos response) {
                parseResponse(response)
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle your error types accordingly.For Timeout & No connection error, you can show 'retry' button.
                // For AuthFailure, you can re login with user credentials.
                // For ClientError, 400 & 401, Errors happening on client side when sending api request.
                // In this case you can check how client is forming the api and debug accordingly.
                // For ServerError 5xx, you can do retry or handle accordingly.
                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                } else if( error instanceof ServerError) {
                } else if( error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                } else if( error instanceof ParseError) {
                } else if( error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                } else if( error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                }
            }
        });
```

I looked at error codes in Flickr Api for instance [flickr.commons.getInstitutions](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.commons.getInstitutions.html), look for a solution to handle them.

in [GsonRequest] class we have a method called parseNetworkResponse:

```
@Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
```

I just passed invalid Flickr API key to my URL, and I expected `NetworkResponse` with statuscode=100, but still I get 200 in the method above!

Then I wonder how can I handle Flickr error codes specified for every methods when I am using Volley?